# Search data from database in textbox to display - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

my problem is i cannot search and cannot disply the values in my texboxes.

what i want is to search the id of each user and display its data to my textbox

How can I do this on this video [This Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n5NYVpFRSB0) in Laravel?

as of now I have ***this***

here is my page [image]

***View***

```
 {!! Form::open(['action' => 'Admin\EmployeeFilemController@search', 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}

                    <input type="text" name="id" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter ID to Search"><br>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" name="search" value="Search Data">
      {!! Form::close() !!}
```

***Controller***

```
   public function search(Request $request){
    $output = "";
    $employees = DB::table('employeefms')->where('id')->get();
    return redirect('/admin/employeemaintenance');
}
```

my ***View Inputs***

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                {{Form::label('employee_no', 'Employee No.')}}
                {{Form::text('employee_no', '',['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Employee No.'])}}
        </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group  col-md-4">
                {{Form::label('last_name', 'Last Name')}}
                {{Form::text('last_name', '',['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Last Name'])}}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group  col-md-4">
                    {{Form::label('first_name', 'First Name')}}
                    {{Form::text('first_name', '',['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'First Name'])}}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group  col-md-4">
                    {{Form::label('middle_name', 'Middle Name')}}
                    {{Form::text('middle_name', '',['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Middle Name'])}}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group  col-md-4">
                    {{Form::label('nick_name', 'Nick Name')}}
                    {{Form::text('nick_name', '',['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Nick Name'])}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to pass the `id` entered by the user in your controller function.

```
$employees = DB::table('employeefms')->where('id')->get();
```

You may have to do the following changes

```
$input = $request->all();
$id = $input['id']
// $employees = DB::table('employeefms')->where('id', $id)->get();

// actually, if 'id' is the primary key, you should be doing
$employee = DB::table('employeefms')->find($id);

// now pass the data to the view where you want to display the record
// like so
return view('name_of_view', compact('employee'));
```

Then, use Laravel's Form-Model binding

```
{!! Form::model($employee,
               ['action' => ['Admin\EmployeeFilemController@update', $employee->id],
               'method' => 'patch' // or whatever method you have defined
               ]) !!}

           // your form fields specified above will go here
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: should i change the view value {{form::text...}} or not?

Comment: You may use Laravel's 'Form-Model binding'. I'll update my answer for the same.

Comment: ok ill wait, that is what im missing i dont know the syntax how to bind it on controller thanks

Comment: hey sir i got an error  `Undefined variable: employee`

Comment: Then change it to `$employees`. Look what name you have given in the statement `$employees = DB::table('employeefms')->where('id', $id)->get();`